# Sprite created with RenderTexture and ReadPixels() has multiplied colors

Tags: unity, rendertexture

[image]I'm working on a character generator that creates thumbnail sprites for each character. I'm using a separate camera that renders to a `RenderTexture`, which is used to create a sprite using `ReadPixels()`. The resulting sprites appear to have their colors multiplied. I'm stumped. I've messed around extensively with lighting and ambient lighting. Right now the only lighting is ambient. I've tried various color formats for the `RenderTexture`. I've tried assigning different materials to the resulting sprite, including the default.

Here is the relevant code, which generates the sprite:

```
IEnumerator GeneratePortrait(Npc npc)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(512, 512);
        RenderTexture.active = rt; //assigned at Start()
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), 0, 0);
        yield return null;
        tex.Apply();
        RenderTexture.active = null;
        npc.sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 512, 512), new Vector2(256, 256));
    }
```

**Update** I tried changing the line that creates the texture to
`Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(512, 512, TextureFormat.ARGB4444, false);`
This shouldn't work; the format of the RenderTexture is the default for the target platform `R8G8B8A8_UNORM` but the result is much better. Still some multiplication happening, but acceptably close.

Comment: This looks to me like it could be a difference in gamma correction. You may want to see if you're saving the texture in linear RGB then reading it as sRGB or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks as always DMGregory, although I'm not sure I follow, or at least understand how to apply your suggestion. The texture and sprite are created on the fly; the texture is applied to the sprite immediately (not saved and then read back in). I did try switching the project's color space from linear to gamma, which _did_ make a perceptible difference, but that's not really a practical solution as it affects many other things... https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LinearRendering-LinearOrGammaWorkflow.html

Comment: Did you try passing linear = true in your Texture2D constructor?

Comment: Actually I overlooked that parameter completely! Thank you for pointing that out. I tried it with the old code and it _does_ improve things but colors are still a little off/ dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `Graphics.CopyTexture()` instead of ReadPixels()**

[CopyTexture Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Graphics.CopyTexture.html)

Not sure why ReadPixels is doing the weird stuff, but CopyTexture doesn't. Here's the updated code:

```
IEnumerator GeneratePortrait(Npc npc)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(512, 512,TextureFormat.RGBA32, 1, false); // need to specify only 1 mipmap level
        RenderTexture.active = rt;
        Graphics.CopyTexture(rt, tex);
        yield return null;
        RenderTexture.active = null;
        npc.sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 512, 512), new Vector2(256, 256));
    }
```